# Why does logically negating an unused optional argument throw an error?

Tags: elisp, optional-parameters, negation

I am attempting to solve [exercise 5.5 of the tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eintr.html#optional-Exercise)

> Write an interactive function with an optional argument that tests whether its argument, a number, is greater than or equal to, or else, less than the value of `fill-column`, and tells you which, in a message. However, if you do not pass an argument to the function, use 56 as a default value.

To do so, I wrote this.

```lisp
(defun foo (&optional x)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (not x) (setq x 59))
  (message (cond ((>= x fill-column) "bigger or equal")
    ((< x fill-column) "smaller"))))
```

When passed no argument (`C-u M-x foo`), it throws the error

> Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p. (4).

What I've been able to gather from experimentation, reasoning, and the debugger is that this function fails on its third line. Clearly, `not` and an optional-but-not-used argument don't agree. I've checked the documentation for `not`, but it did not help. This gives me my question: **Why does negating an unused argument throw an error?**

I've not yet fully grasped the debugger in Emacs, so I'm sorry that I was unable to solve this myself. I'm a total beginner with both Emacs and Emacs Lisp. I am not a new programmer or even a new Lisper. I already know Scheme. Feel free to teach me how to fish.

Comment: `(4)` is not `nil` and so `(not x)` returns `nil` and therefore the `if` form evaluates the `message` form (being its "else" clause) which very soon evaluates `(>= x fill-column)` which requires `x` to be a number.

Comment: Note also that "When passed no argument (C-u M-x foo)" is a contradiction, as using `C-u` *does* pass an argument (you've explicitly used an `interactive` spec which causes that).

Answer (score 1):

`(4)` is referring to what caused the error. It's the list containing four. Recall what [the tutorial says](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eintr.html#Optional-Arguments) about `C-u`.

> If you don’t type a number, `C-u` defaults to a cons cell with a 4

Presumably, `not`'s error is referring to this.

Comment: In fact the error will be due to `(>= x fill-column)` which requires a numeric argument.  There's no issue using `not` with a list argument, as `not` only cares whether or not the argument is `nil`.

Comment: See `C-h i g (elisp)Prefix Command Arguments` for more about prefix arguments and, in conjunction with that, note carefully in `C-h f interactive` the difference between `(interactive "P")` and `(interactive "p")`

Comment: @phils Ah. Clearly I need to learn more about debugging in Emacs.